# Does spreading blood around the edge of the garden work to deter animals?

Tags: pest-control

I've noticed that a lot of animal sprays have blood in their brews, will just spreading pure blood around the edges of the garden send animals far away to keep my plants safe?

Comment: Related: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16269/how-effective-is-cows-blood-as-a-deer-deterent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was young decades ago, my mother used to put blood meal around tulips and crocus to protect them from rabbits. It's also a mild fertilizer. It did seem to work, but if it got wet its effectiveness disappeared and it had to be reapplied. Not worth the work in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

What about the smell? Will your neighbours put up with that. Besides, blood will eventually turn your garden into a breeding ground for all kinds of bacteria. A simple chicken wire might be a better option but for some reason im sure you've thought of that and have deemed it not fit for the purpose.

Comment: My neighbors are the bog, unless you count 500 feet away through the woods, so what neighbors?